# macOS get notification for connection creation in the system

Tags: objective-c, sockets, cocoa, lsof

I was wondering if there's any user-space way to register socket creation function and get notification for each new socket created and inspect its characteristics (ip/port/protocol).

Perhaps `lsof` or `fsevents` has some programmatic api for this task ?

thanks